# MySQL vs SQL Commands

Tags: mysql, sql, command

As far as I can gather, there are commands which are native to SQL such as `SELECT` and `DELETE`, and there are commands which are part of MySQL but not native to SQL such as `use` and `describe`. Have I got that right?

In [this link](https://gist.github.com/hofmannsven/9164408) the difference seems to be implied by having the MySQL commands in lower case. Is there a resource which shows which commands belong to which group i.e. native SQL vs MySQL-specific?

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a language standard. Defined by organisations like ISO, ANSI, DIN.

Each SQL database system provides SQL, but with different scope and syntax. So you can learn the standard, but than you have to look for the distinctions. Or you directly learn a syntax of a specific database system. It depends on your purposes.

By the way the commands themself are case-insensitive. So it is indifferent if you write "select" or "SELECT". I prefer lower case because it is easy to write. Other prefer upper case because it is easy to read. In many projects the convention is upper case.